# Отправить картинку с текстом в python телеграмм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я только начал изучать python и не могу найти решения как отправить мне текст с картинкой в телеграмме.
Пробовал вот так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    global num_start
    num_start += 1
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in [' Кнопка 1', ' Кнопка 2', ' Кнопка 3', 'Кнопка 4']])   
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, open('static/welc.webp', 'rb'),\n '✌️ Приветствуем Вас, ' + '' + message.chat.first_name + '' + '!\n\n'
                                      ' Bit+Coin - это моментальный обмен Bitcoin на Qiwi, Сбербанк,'
                                      ' Яндекс.Деньги и Webmoney\n\n'
                                      '❕А так же бесплатное хранилище Ваших BTC\n\n', reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode="Html")
```

Вставил вот такой код в **bot.send_message(message.chat.id,**

```
open('static/welc.webp', 'rb'),
```

Но чего не происходит, как правильно сделать что бы отправлял фото и текст в одном посту.

Вот как тут например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

Для отправки фотографий используйте метод send_photo:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    global num_start
    num_start += 1
    text = f"✌️ Приветствуем Вас, {message.chat.first_name}!\n\n" \
           f" Bit+Coin - это моментальный обмен Bitcoin на Qiwi Сбербанк Яндекс.Деньги и Webmoney\n\n" \
           f"❕А так же бесплатное хранилище Ваших BTC\n\n"
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in [' Кнопка 1', ' Кнопка 2', ' Кнопка 3', 'Кнопка 4']]) 

    with open('static/welc.webp', 'rb') as photo:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=text, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode="HTML"
```

Comment: не помогло, с таким кодом он дает ошибку 

 File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot\Bot.py", line 75
   '?? <b>Bit+Coin</b> - это моментальный обмен <b>Bitcoin на Qiwi, Сбербанк,'
ndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Исправил :)

Comment: Супер, помог очень, сейчас буду разбираться что бы понять как это сделать потом самому

Comment: Если ответ помог, то можете отметить его как правильный, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь к боту: @HostImgBot
Отправляешь ему нужное фото, в ответ получишь ссылку на фото
Или сам закидываешь на любой хостинг к примеру ВК, кликнешь ПКМ и выбираешь копировать ссылку

```
text = 'blablabla' 
img = 'ссылка' 
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{text}\n{img}')
```